# R dply select over list of names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a bunch of data frames which I need to loop over and row merge certain variables.

I was trying to put all my list names in an array as:

```
list_names <- c('list1','list2','list3')
```

And then performing an `sapply`:

```
output <- sapply(list_names, function(x) rbind(main list, 
    select(as.name(x), col1, col2, col3, col4)))
```

the fisrt error I run into is :

```
Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I think the select statement doesn't like that I'm passing in `x` and not a variable name. is there a way I can say that x is a variable name? I thought `as.name(x)` would do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `get`, which retrieves the data by column name:

**Reproducible example:**

```
library(dplyr)

list_names = c("mtcars", "mtcars")

lapply(list_names, function(x) rbind(mtcars[1:3], select(get(x), mpg, cyl, disp)))
```

Another method would be to convert each `list_names` to `sym` (from `rlang`) and tidy evaluate it when calling `select`:

```
library(rlang)

lapply(list_names, function(x) rbind(mtcars[1:3], select(eval_tidy(sym(x)), mpg, cyl, disp)))
```

Base R Equivalent:

```
lapply(list_names, function(x) rbind(mtcars[1:3], select(eval(as.name(x)), mpg, cyl, disp)))
```

**OP's example:**

```
output <- lapply(list_names, function(x) rbind(main_list, 
    select(get(x), col1, col2, col3, col4)))
```

or:

```
output <- lapply(list_names, function(x) rbind(main_list, 
    select(eval(as.name(x)), col1, col2, col3, col4)))
```